# Elastic Beanstalk does not load the Django admin static files

Tags: django, django-admin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have static files in a specific app in my project, and I add that route in my config file as my static route for EB, and as I do this EB doesn't load required CSS files for django admin page.
My python.config looks like:
    option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: MyProject/wsgi.py
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
            /static/: "MyApp/static/"

And I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   /static/admin/css/responsive.css:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell Django where to store static files, define STATIC_ROOT in settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

And type the commande:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```