# Why won't elastic beanstalk render css for the django admin site?

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following this guide on deploying a django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

After running eb open, the css for the admin site does not render. It works when running the development server at 127.0.0.1:8000/admin but not when deployed to EB.

I have followed this guidance but it is still not working
[Elastic Beanstalk does not load the Django admin static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204709/elastic-beanstalk-does-not-load-the-django-admin-static-files)

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `.ebextension/djnago.config` in your project root dir. And code for loading static assests is below:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

I used this for django 4.0 on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: Can you please mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: sorry im not the author

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Linux 2 you should add the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles` option setting to your .ebextension configs. Don't forget to run migrate and collect static commands.

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true

  02_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py collectstatic"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

This should work for this setup in your settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: I also had to do: python manage.py collectstatic